# Angularjs table code not working

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular. I have created one html and I am getting values from rest services. I use ng-repeat to put those values into table but the values are not showing in the table without any errors. Please guys check my code once.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Project Management</title>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" ng-href="http://bootswatch.com/flatly/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://bootswatch.com/flatly/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        .table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
            background: #f1f1f1 !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <style>
        table {
            border: 1px solid #666;
            width: 100%;
        }
        th {
            background: #f8f8f8;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding: 2px;
        }
    </style>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info pull-right btn-sm">Logout</button>

    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="ContactController">

            <button ng-click="add()">Project Details</button>
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <tr>
                    <th>projectid</th>
                    <th>projectname</th>
                    <th>claintid</th>
                    <th>projectstatus</th>
                    <th>prjstartdate</th>
                    <th>prjenddate</th>
                    <th>lastmodified</th>
                    <th>prjpinurl</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="person in people">

                    <td>{{person.projectid}}</td>
                    <td>{{person.projectname}}</td>
                    <td>{{person.claintid}}</td>
                    <td>{{person.projectstatus}}</td>
                    <td>{{person.prjstartdate}}</td>
                    <td>{{person.prjenddate}}</td>
                    <td>{{person.lastmodified}}</td>
                    <td>{{person.prjpinurl}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" ng-click="Edit(contact)">Edit</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" ng-click="Remove(contact)">Remove</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>



        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

        function ContactController($scope, $http) {
            //   $scope.contacts = ["hi@email.com", "hello@email.com"];
            $scope.people = [];
            $scope.add = function() {


                // $scope.contacts.push($scope.newcontact);
                // $scope.newcontact = "";

                $http.get('http://localhost:8080/ProjectManagement/REST/GetProject/Details').success(function(data, status, headers, config, response) {

                    var json = JSON.stringify(data);

                    var getresponseText = JSON.parse(json);
                    var prjdetails = getresponseText.responseText;

                    var fields = getresponseText.split("|");


                    var projectid = fields[0];
                    var projectname = fields[1];
                    var claintid = fields[2];
                    var projectstatus = fields[3];
                    var prjstartdate = fields[4];
                    var prjenddate = fields[5];
                    var lastmodified = fields[6];
                    var prjpinurl = fields[7];

                    claim = '';

                    claim = '[{';
                    claim += '"projectid": "' + projectid + '", ';
                    claim += '"projectname": "' + projectname + '", ';
                    claim += '"claintid": "' + claintid + '", ';
                    claim += '"projectstatus": "' + projectstatus + '", ';
                    claim += '"prjstartdate": "' + prjstartdate + '", ';
                    claim += '"prjenddate": "' + prjenddate + '", ';
                    claim += '"lastmodified": "' + lastmodified + '", ';
                    claim += '"prjpinurl": "' + prjpinurl + '", ';
                    claim += '}]';
                    alert("before" + claim)
                    $scope.people = claim;


                }).error(function(data, status, headers, config, response) {


                });
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: its very urgent guys pls if any one know what i have done mistake pls post the same

Comment: Nothing is ***urgent*** here. Need more information. Is ajax request succeeding and returning proper data as expected? what troubleshooting have you done? Just saying `it's not working` is not a proper problem description

Comment: i am getting response and i am placing that in json using claim = '[{';
            claim += '"projectid": "'+ projectid+ '", ';
            claim += '"projectname": "'+ projectname+ '", ';
            claim += '"claintid": "'+ claintid+ '", ';
            claim += '"projectstatus": "'+ projectstatus + '", ';
            claim += '"prjstartdate": "'+prjstartdate+ '", ';
            claim += '"prjenddate": "'+ prjenddate + '", ';
            claim += '"lastmodified": "'+ lastmodified + '", ';
            claim += '"prjpinurl": "'+ prjpinurl + '", ';
            claim += '}]';

Comment: Why are you manually creating json when angular expects javascript objects and arrays? Why do you stringify the response data? Show sample of actual json sent from server

Comment: i am getting from rest service 1|Sample project 1|1|WIP|null|null|2015-08-24 16:38:39.0|http://hcup-us.ahrq.gov/toolssoftware/ccs/ccs.jsp

Comment: Should be returning proper object/array structure from REST. That pipe delimiter structure makes no sense. Most of the time you can assign the response directly to the scope without any parsing

Comment: but we can change proper format  using json right why it is not working

Comment: You need to get a better understanding of what json is....it's a string data transfer format. Inside your code you should be working with actual javascript arrays and objects not json strings

Comment: Can you please post one sample `claim json` i.e `$scope.people` by doing either `console.dir($scope.people)` or debugging through your console

Answer (score 0):

Try to build the array of people without building the claims string. the following should do the work (assuming the projectId, projectname, etc. have the expected values):

```
$scope.people = [
    {
        projectid: projectId,
        projectname: projectname,
        claintid: claintid,
        projectstatus: projectstatus,
        prjstartdate: prjstartdate,
        prjenddate: prjenddate,
        lastmodified: lastmodified,
        prjpinurl: prjpinurl
    }
];
```

Comment: Might solve the short term problem but there is no need to create that string in the first place

Comment: I agree. I guess we could use the actual response from the service.

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token is coming  when i use $scope.people = JSON.parse(claim);

Comment: I changed my response. Take a look if that gives you an idea how you can build the array of people.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing exactly what the original response looks like it's hard to say for sure, but it looks like you are doing a lot of unnecessary work.

What happens if you just change your javascript to:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
function ContactController($scope,$http) {
 //   $scope.contacts = ["hi@email.com", "hello@email.com"];
 $scope.people = [];
 $scope.add = function() {

  // $scope.contacts.push($scope.newcontact);
  // $scope.newcontact = "";

  $http.get('http://localhost:8080/ProjectManagement/REST/GetProject/Details').success(function(data, status, headers, config,response){
        $scope.people = data;
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config,response) {

    });
  }
}
```

`
It looks like you already have a valid JSON response coming back from your REST service.

Comment: no i am not getting valid json i am getting response 1|Sample project 1|1|WIP|null|null|2015-08-24 16:38:39.0|http://hcup-us.ahrq.gov/toolssoftware/ccs/ccs.jsp   then i am converting in to json

Comment: @chandrak if you can change that pipe delimit response data to an object in REST and send object as json all you would need to do is set response to scope variable and remove all your other code that parses the response. Your format makes no sense